# How to not apply before_filter for root route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `before_filter` called `check_login` that looks something like this:

```
def check_login
  if not session[:user_id]
    flash[:error] = "Please log in to continue"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

I then put this `before_filter` in my application controller, and then exclude it in my login controller (with `skip_before_filter :check_login`)

The problem is that when the user hits the homepage for the first time (i.e. just localhost:3000), it will redirect them to the login page with the `flash[:error]` message displaying. However, for the homepage, I just want to show the login form. What's the cleanest way to handle this 'special-case'? I thought about putting the `skip_before_filter` in the controller that handles the homepage, but I didn't think this was very DRY, since if I change the homepage in the routes file, I'll have to also change the location of the `skip_before_filter`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add some action in your filter

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :check_login, :only => [:login]

  def login
  end
end
```

And in Application Controller, "blank?" check on presence and nil. It useful

```
def check_login
  if session[:user_id].blank?
    flash[:error] = "Please log in to continue"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add named action for your homepage:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end
end
```

And then check the current action in your callback:

```
def check_login
  if not session[:user_id]
    flash[:error] = "Please log in to continue" unless params[:action] == "home"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```